# Get executed query from BigQuery jobId

Tags: google-bigquery

With the [BigQuery Job List API](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) I retrieve a list of executed jobs and their status. Is there a quick way to retrieve the executed query by job reference?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Necessary information can be found at:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get

Where a job id and a project id are required.